# iPhone/iPad App Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I was testing for memory leaks by running the Leaks tool to analyze on the device. I saw a bunch of leaks like:

GeneralBlock-128 (or some other number), Responsible Library is Foundation, Responsible Frame is NSPlaceholderMutableString.

What do these mean and how to fix them?? I have A LOT of these!! Please help. Thanks.

Comment: When you'll double click on the line, you'll see the code that is leaking, try checking in this way, and paste code that is leaking.

Answer (score 1):

NSPlaceholderMutableString is the class used in allocating new instances of NSMutableString. Check where you're creating these objects (charge the Foundation libraries to its callers in the data mining inspector) and you'll find where to audit your code. Beware that the Leaks tool is not 100% successful so there is some chance that you're seeing a false +ve, but it's still definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response... but can you please be more clear on this: "(charge the Foundation libraries to its callers in the data mining inspector)". I have no idea how to do that??